# Mysql connection for visual studio 2005

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database, windows-8, visual-studio-2005

I installed Visual Studio 2005 in **Windows 8.1** and need to use **MYSQL** as database.

So can I use **MYSQL** as database for Visual Studio 2005 in Windows 8? Which **MYSQL** version is supported?

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: I hope you mean Visual Studio 2015

Comment: If what you are looking for is the MySQL connector for Visual Studio, check this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-visual-studio-install.html. It will give you an idea of what versions of both MySQL and Visual Studio are supported